# How else part work in continue statement?

Tags: python, for-loop, for-else

I'm not sure how the `continue` statement is interpreted when it is inside a `for` loop with an `else` clause.

If the condition is true, the `break` will exit from a `for` loop and `else` part will not be executed. And if the condition is False then `else` part will be executed.

But, what about `continue` statement? I tested it seems that the after the `continue` statement is reached, the `else` part will be executed. Is this true?? Here is a code example:

```
# when condition found and it's `true` then `else` part is executing :

edibles = ["ham", "spam", "eggs","nuts"]
for food in edibles:
    if food == "spam":
        print("No more spam please!")
        continue
    print("Great, delicious " + food)

else:
    print("I am so glad: No spam!")
print("Finally, I finished stuffing myself")`
```

If I remove "spam" from the list, now the condition is always `false` and never found but still the `else` part is executed:

```
edibles = ["ham","eggs","nuts"]
for food in edibles:
    if food == "spam":
        print("No more spam please!")
        continue
    print("Great, delicious " + food)

else:
    print("I am so glad: No spam!")
print("Finally, I finished stuffing myself")
```

Comment: `for/else` use only `break` and `else` doesn't care for `continue` - it is `for-break-else` construction. (see @Charles answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `else` part will be executed in both cases. 
`else` part executed when loop terminate when condition didn't found.Which is what is happening in your code. But it will also work same without `continue` statement.

now what about break statement's else part, Break statement's else part will be executed only if:

- If the loop completes normally without any break.
- If the loop doesn't encounter a break.

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) i like your explanation can you please answer this question ?  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006300/how-two-recursion-function-in-program-works#40006300

Answer (score 5):

With a `for` loop in Python, the `else` block is executed when the loop finishes normally, i.e. there is no `break` statement. A `continue` does not affect it either way.

If the for loop ends because of a `break` statement, then `else` block will not execute. If the loop exits normally (no `break`), then the `else` block will be executed.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

> When used with a loop, the else clause has more in common with the else clause of a try statement than it does that of if statements: a try statement’s else clause runs when no exception occurs, and a loop’s else clause runs when no break occurs.

I always remember it because of how Raymond Hettinger [describes it](https://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go?t=17m44s). He said it should have been called `nobreak` instead of `else`. (That's also a good video that explains the usefulness of the for-else construct)

Example:

```
numbers = [1,2,3]
for number in numbers:
    if number == 4:
        print("4 was found")
        break
else:
    print("4 was not found")
```

When you run the above code, since `4` is not in the list, the loop will not `break` and the `else` clause will print. If you add `4` to the list and run it again, it will `break` and the `else` will not print. In most other languages, you would have to add some sentinel boolean like `found` and make it `True` if you find a `4`, then only print the statement after the loop if `found` is `False`.

Comment: And of course if the `for` (or `while`) loop is in a function and you exit the loop prematurely using `return` then the `else` clause won't be executed either.